# Why is function defined by defun not bound

Tags: functions, symbols

## intro

Sometimes I want to generate a function programmatically as opposed to defining
one with `defun`. You may wondering why I'd want to do this. Well, it's
complicated but just bear with me for a moment.

```
(defun void-defun (fn)
  (let ((name (gensym "void-defun-")))
    (eval
     `(progn
        (message "Created function: %S" name)
        (defun ,name ()
          (funcall #',fn))))
    name))
```

## problem

When I test whether the function is bound with the following code, all is well.

```
(let ((fn (void-defun (lambda () 2))))
  (and (fboundp fn) (= 2 (funcall fn)) fn))
;; => void-defun-69
```

## after the test

However, after evaluating this test code and calling the function (whose name I
know from the `*messages*` buffer) I get a void-function error. I expected the
function to be bound as indicated by my test. It is as if the function was bound
temporarily for the execution of my test form then unbound again.

```
;; This 69 is just as an example of a name I could get.
(funcall #'void-defun-69)
;; => eval: Symbol’s function definition is void: void-defun-69
```

## question

Why does this happen? And how can I avoid this?

Comment: Why don't you use macros to define functions programmatically? Why `eval`?

Comment: The whole story is that I have a macro called `defun!` which is the same as
`defun` except that after the docstring it is possible to supply keyword
arguments such as `(defun! fn () (:expire t) (:after message) (message "Just
messaged"))`. This would result in a function that is an after advice to
`message` and would unbind itself after its first call. I have wanted to call
this macro via a function e.g. (void-defun (lambda () (message "hi") :expire t
:after #'hi).

I've heard it is not good practice to use eval. Before this I had `(funcall
(backquote (lambda () ...))` to avoid `eval`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you assign a function to an *uninterned* symbol, then naturally you won't find that function on the *interned* symbol of that name -- they are two completely independent objects.

Your `void-defun` is *returning* that uninterned symbol, and in your successful test you are *capturing* that symbol, so naturally you can successfully call its function.

In your unsuccessful test you are trying to use the function of the interned symbol by that name.

You may be looking for the `intern` function to obtain the interned symbol by the supplied name.

See also: <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Creating Symbols`